# Ruby DevKIt Install

Tags: ruby, devkit

I have installed `ruby2.0.0-p598-x64` and I've also unpacked `DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx_2`.

but when I give `gem install json --platform=ruby` in `cmd` it says

> could not find a valid gem 'json' (>=0)

here is why:

> Unable to download data from https://rybtgems.org/-SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix for this session;

```
gem install xxxx --source=http://rubygems.org
```

If you want to fix for always, it's depend on your OS. This error is normaly on Windows.

Windows way;

1) Download this [file : cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
(Right click and save as)

2) Go to the system proprieties (Windows + Break), Advanced system proprieties (left sidebar), environment variable, and add new for your user.

3) `Name : SSL_CERT_FILE` and `Value : X:\XXXX\cacert.pem`

4)Restart your command prompt.

Linux/Mac (not tested);

Force HTTPS : `sudo gem sources -a http://rubygems.org`

Comment: My operating system is windows. Nothing downloads after I click the link.

Comment: I forgot, you need to right click and save as to your location ( i recommend your Ruby installation folder ).